# Is it possible to pull specific language from custom labels by changing the users language

Tags: apex, customlabel, language

Using anonymous apex in my dev sandbox I did the following:

```
User myUser = new User();
myUser.Id = UserInfo.getUserId();
myUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'sv';
myUser.LocaleSidKey = 'sv';
update myUser;
system.debug('My label: ' + Label.myLabel);
```

However when I system.debugged a particular label(that I had previously set up with a swedish translation) it came back as the masterlabel in English. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the complete code sample? What label and how are you retrieving the label value

Comment: @Raspi I edited my code sample.

Comment: One of the options could be using VF language attribute and getContent method, so you can specify language as parameter and get label in proper language without changing current user language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround for it. Its bit ugly . Use it if its last resort.

You have to define a Apex Rest Endpoint to get custom lable(I am not sure if you can use Normal SF rest)

The flow goes like this.

1) Use [Execute Anon endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm) to update the user locale or [Standard Sobject Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm) endpoint to change locale.

2) Use the custom apex rest endpoint to get the custom label in the recently updated locale.

I haven't tested it, but looks like it would work. It will use 2 callouts.

Comment: Are you saying build 2 end points - 1 to change the user locale and 1 to pull the custom? I am confused about 1) where you say "execute anon endpoint".

Comment: @Arthlete updated links. You need build 1 single rest endpoint to get lables. Updating user locale can be done using standard rest endpoints

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only get the translation as it was as of the beginning of the transaction.

Comment: Can you have a look at my workaround? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/249031/19118

Answer (score 3):

Like kurunve mentioned above, use a Visualforce page as a template to be read from Apex.

```
<apex:page contentType="application/json" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" 
           standardStylesheets="false" language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lang}">
{!$Label[$CurrentPage.parameters.label]}
</apex:page>

public with sharing class Translate {
    public static String translate(String labelApiName, String language) {
        PageReference r = Page.Translator; // the page
        r.getParameters().put('lang', language);
        r.getParameters().put('label', labelApiName);
        return r.getContent().toString();
    }
}
```